# Increment array values?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have this array:

```
var arr = [2,2,2,2,2];
```

And I want to loop through that array and create a new array that looks like this:

```
var arr2 = [2,4,6,8,10];
```

What I need is a loop that will go through first array and increment next value with previous value.

I did something like this:

```
var arr = [2,2,2,2,2];
var arr2 = [];

for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr2[i] = arr[i] + arr[i+1];
}

console.log(arr2);
```

But its not what I really need!

How would you do this?

Comment: The problem in the code is arr[4+1] i.e. arr[arr.length+1] doesn't exist and causing NaN...

Comment: _its not what I really need_ This doesn't accurately describe a problem. Can you provide a non-trivial example of your expected input and output? Using `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]` is masking your intention.

Comment: _"What I need is a loop that will go through first array and increment next value with previous value"_ Is "previous value" value before increment ? e.g., `[2,4,4,4,4] ?`

Comment: Previous value is value after increment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the previous value, or `0` if no such value exists

```js
var arr  = [2,2,2,2,2];
var arr2 = []; // <----- new array

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
 arr2[i] = arr[i] + (arr2[i-1] || 0)
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr2, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: you missed the " create a new array" part of the question

Comment: If I change original array to: var arr = [2,2,5,2,2]; It won't work as intended :(

Comment: @PixelPusher - then you get `[2, 4, 9, 11, 13]` which seems correct, what are you expecting ?

Comment: @PixelPusher you'll have to re-perform the new array creation every time you change the original array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [2,2,2,2,2];
var arr2 = [];
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   arr2[i] = arr[i] + (arr2[i-1] || 0);
}

console.log(arr2);

[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: @PixelPusher this answer is exactly the same code as in adeneo's answer posted several minutes beforehand.

Comment: Yeah looks like he answered before so i will credit him for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

> you should write like this:

```
var arr = [2,2,2,2,2];
var arr2 = [];
var value = 0;
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ 
    value =  value + arr[i];
    arr2[i] = value;  
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for.